# Changing origin in Structuring element in octave/matlab (image processing)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

I am trying to apply morphological operations on image in octave/matlab. 
I need to use structuring elements for using operations like dialate, erode.
The origin of structuring elements is set by default using 
this:

origin = floor((size(nhood)+1)/2)

reference : http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/strel.html

i need to change this origin to some other element of the structuring element. FYI I am using flat structuring element.

I couldn't find any document for this. Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right you can shift the structuring element using [translate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/translate.html?searchHighlight=strel).

Example from the help page:

```
se = strel(ones(3))

%// Translate it 2 rows up and 2 columns to the left

se2 = translate(se,[-2 -2])
```

Giving this:

[image]

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Great then glad to help!